# Making protractor tests run on different Urls parallely (same Browser)

Tags: selenium, protractor, e2e-testing

I want to run tests in parallel. Tried to use `shardTestFiles:true` with `maxInstance:2`. But what I need is being able to specify different URLs for these test instances to hit, as my application is not completely stateless.

I tried to give multiple chrome capabilities to achieve this, and identifying by name. like this:

```
multiCapabilities: [
  {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
     name: 'browser1'               
  },
  {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
     name: 'browser2'               
  }
]
```

But protractor does not shard the tests between capabilities.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

That's a good question and its definitely possible. Use `browser.getProcessedConfig` to fetch the current browser's `name` at run-time and modify `baseUrl` accordingly. Refer [browser.getProcessedConfig API doc](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.getProcessedConfig)

Modify your `on-prepare` function as below

```
onPrepare: function() {
    browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function(config){
        switch(config.capabilities.name) {
            case 'browser1':
                browser.baseUrl = 'https://angularjs.org/'
                break;
            case 'browser2':
                browser.baseUrl = 'http://www.protractortest.org/'
                break;
            default:
                browser.baseUrl = 'https://builtwith.angularjs.org/'
                break;
        }
    })
},
```

Comment: This does not help with sharding though.